# How to switch default calendar in Google Calendars

Tags: google-calendar

I understand from other questions that the first Calendar listed is your default calendar.

I have 8 calendars (not all visible). I want Calendar in the fourth position to become my Default, but I don't want to lose the info in my other calendars (including the current default).

Other responses seemed to solve changing default to a new calendar. I imagine switching defaults still involves some exporting, unsubscribing and importing, but I'd appreciate the exact 'script.'

Comment: It's not possible to set an user created calendar as the default calendar.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, export the data, clear the calendars, import the data and rename the calendars to match the content.

1. Export from your default calendar (Calendar A)
2. Export from the calendar you want to swap with (Calendar B)
3. Create a new calendar (Calendar C) and import events from your previously exported Calendar A file (and check that you've done it correctly)
4. Clear your default calendar (calendar settings > remove (this will clear the calendar rather than delete it)
5. Import Calendar B data to Calendar A
6. Delete the existing calendar B
7. Rename the default calendar to B
8. Rename calendar C as calendar A

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to be obtuse, but any detail re the parenthetical remark in Point 3. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The only way so far: display ONLY the calendar you want to use as default for new events.

Comment: Perhaps not the best answer for the OP, but a LOT easier to do if you only want to use a single calendar, but a different calendar than the default. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the calendar you want to be the default so that it will be listed as the first in lexicographic order. You can rename the calendar by clicking the three dots that appear at the right side of the calendar name (in the list of subscribed calendars) and then choose "Settings and sharing": you will get a tab where you are allowed to change the calendar name.
In my case, for not really changing the name of the calender I wanted to be the default, I just added a space before its name. It became the 1st and the default one. Time: 20 secs.

Comment: Doesn't work as of September 2020. Additional calendars are ordered lexicographically in the list, but the one Google chooses as default is always on top, regardless of its name or the names of the other calendars.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you figured this out or not but depending on what your doing this own will depend how you need to do it. If you go to your google on the internet and log out of all accounts and then log into the one that you want as default and then log in to the others it will work.

If your own your phone go to settings and turn off all the calanders but the default one you want and then you can turn the others back on and then you can add events to the “default” email.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two answers above and then it still works today.

Change the name of the one you want first to start with a space or underscore (_)

Uncheck the Google default calendar. (Or else Google will default to it)

If you need the stuff in the unchecked Google default calendar you can  export just that one calendar and reimport it under a new name, but you don't need to do multiples.